# Different "Master" Tables and Same "Child" Tables

Tags: database-design

I am working on Student Life Cycle management system which is in the design stage. Right now I am creating the database structure.

My requirement is as follows: Every year a student faces three term tests, and I want to store all marks related to these three terms. These marks are represented in digits.

According to the requirement above, the table structure can be configured in the following way:

1. term-test-master

   ```
   -------------------------------------------
    exam-id | exam-year | batch-number | term 
   -------------------------------------------
   ```
2. term-test-marks

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------
    subject-id | exam-id | student-index | marks
   ----------------------------------------------
   ```

In the second scenario, all students face to end school examination and their marks are represented as a letter. Both "master" tables are a little bit the same but not exactly. But required column of `end-exam-marks` all most same to `-test-marks`.  But `marks` value is represented by a letter.

1. end-school-master

   ```
   ----------------------------------------
    exam-id | exam-year | exam-name | term
   ----------------------------------------
   ```
2. end-exam-marks

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------
    subject-id | exam-id | student-index | marks
   ----------------------------------------------
   ```

*Note*: I believe one of the applicable functional dependencies is `{ exam-year } → { exam-id }`.

Can I use the same `term-test-marks` table in both situations with marks with VARCHAR datatype, or should I use two separate "child" tables for separate "master" tables?

Comment: Do not draw your tables. Post their DDLs, including current foreign key dependencies. *Can i use same term-test-marks table in both situation with marks with varchar data type? or should i use two separate child table for separate master table?* Does you can use the dictionary of common words and the dictionary of special terms for to translate one article? Does you can to use the same dictionary for to translate a newspaper article and an article from special magazine? The answer is "Yes" in both cases, is it? ... and the same for your question.

Comment: @Akina i think, i understood answer,from your explanation